# where is the source code of qt designer default widgets

Tags: qt, qt-designer

I want to create a **qt designer plugin** that behaves like the builtin **QTreeWidget** but i cant find the source code used to create any of the built in widgets. Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my Qt installation (4.7.1), the designer plugin source code can be found in

```
<QTDIR>/tools/designer/src/plugins
```

Comment: The source for most widgets not in there

Comment: Well, that's because the standard widgets are not implemented as explicit plugins. The entries in the "Widget Box" are defined in `<QTDIR>\tools\designer\src\components\widgetbox\widgetbox.xml` and directly relate the entries to the corresponding widget class.